# Weak derivative vanishes implies constant with restpect to that variable

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a connected open set in $ \mathbb{R^n}$. Let $\Omega = A \times B$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n - 1}$ and  $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ are open.  $f \in W^{1,2} (\Omega)$. If the weak derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} = 0$ in $\Omega$, then show that $f$ does not depend on $x_n$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$.

**Solution:** For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, write $x=(\bar{x},x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$. Choosing test function of the form $\psi_1 \in C^{\infty}_c(A), \psi_2 \in C^{\infty}_c (B)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\int_{A} \int_B f(\bar{x},x_n)  \psi_1 \frac{d\psi_2}{dx_n}\,d{x} = -\int_{A} \int_B\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} (\bar{x},x_n)\psi_1 \psi_2 \,d{x} =0.
\end{equation}
So for a.e. $\bar{x} \in A$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{B} f(\bar{x},x_n) \frac{d\psi_2}{dx_n}  \,d{x_n} =0.
\end{equation}
So for a fixed $\bar{x} \in A$, the weak derivative of the function $f(\bar{x},x_n) :{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $0$. So $f(\bar{x},x_n)$ does not depend on $x_n$ a.e. This completes the proof.

Comment: How are you defining "does not depend on $x_i$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$"?

Comment: Note that the corresponding statement for classical derivatives is false: If $\partial_{x_i} f=0$ in $\Omega$ it doesn't follow that $f$ doesn't depend on $x_i$ (think of half an annulus)

Comment: Please check the edited question.

Comment: So you mean locally $f$ doesn't depend on $x_i$. You should probably make that explicit in the body of the question.

Comment: I do not think it is local. Since $y_0$ is arbitrary, $f$ does not depend on $x_i$ in whole $\Omega$.

Comment: You're implicitly decomposing your domain into the product space $A\times X_i$. This can only be done locally. Again, think of half an annulus.

Comment: You are right. I have changed accordingly. Could you tell more about the annulus and how the case for classical partial derivative fails?